# why it reverse the opration after it do?

Tags: javascript, recursion, sum

I try to add a numbers from 1 to 10 by JavaScript using the concept of recursion and it didn't work as intended. it revers the operation and it come up with the first result and when i use variable to store the result i get it come up with *undefined*.
here is the code

```
var total = 0, count = 1;
function sum(total, count){
    if(count <= 3){
        total +=count;
        count++;
        sum(total, count);
    }else{
        return total;
    };
}
var result = sum(total, count);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `sum(total, count);` -> `return sum(total, count);`

Comment: So what is your expected result? 55?

Comment: `function sum (n) { if (n == 0) return 0; else return n + sum(n - 1) }` `sum(10)` yields `55` which is (10 + 9 + 8 + ... + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning from your first `if` condition. Default return value for any function is `undefined`.

```js
var total = 0, count = 1;
function sum(total, count){
    if(count <= 3){
        total +=count;
        count++;
        return sum(total, count);
    }else{
        return total;
    };
}
var result = sum(total, count);
console.log(result);
```